# Including Files in Ruby Questions

Tags: ruby, include, load, require

- I am very new to Ruby so could you please suggest the best practice to separating files and including them.
- What is the preferred design structure of the file layout. When do you decide to separate the algorithm into a new file?
- When do you use **load** to include other files and when do you use **require**?
- And is there a performance hit when you include files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- I make one file per class, except classes that are small helper classes, not needed by other files. I separate my different modules in subdirectories also.
- The difference between `load` and `require` is `require` will only load the file once, even if it's called multiple times, while `load` will load it again regardless of whether it's been loaded before. You'll almost always want to use `require`, except maybe in `irb` when you want to manually want to reload a file.
- I'm not sure on the performance hit. When you `load` or `require` a file, the interpreter has to interpret the file. Most Ruby's will compile it to virtual machine code after being required. Obviously, `require` is more performant when the file may have already been included once, because it may not have to load it again.